# how to input value in name and id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input in html form and I need to send them to script. it has both name and id .

```html
 <p>
        <select onchange="myFunction(this.value)"  name="shippcity" id="shippcity">
  
            <option value="0">state</option>
         
        </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="calc_shipping_city" id="shipping_city" value="" />// will be removed

 </p>

<script>
function myFunction(val) {
 if ( val === '' ) {
   
 }
 else { 
  //input val to name="calc_shipping_city" and id="shipping_city"
   document.getElementById("shipping_city").value = val; 
          }

   
}
</script>
```

there is this code too from woocomerce:

```
      <?php
}

$my_city = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_city();
$my_city = explode('-', $my_city);
if(isset($my_city) && intval($my_city[0]) > 0 ){
    ?>
    set_initial_val('shipp', 'city', <?php echo $my_city[0]; ?>);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each input element has a `value` property which you can set.

```
function myFunction(val) {
  if ( val === '' ) {

  }
  else {
   document.getElementById("shipping_city").value = val;              
   document.getElementById("shippcity").form.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this. but it seems the second command doesn't work.(document.getElementById("shippcity").form.submit();)
nothing happend onchage.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your code example, but your form elements need to live inside of a `<form>` element for that second line to work.  From what I see in your code they only exist inside of a `<p>` element.

Comment: the problem is from shipping_city ID . that line does not work.

Comment: thank you very much.problem  solved. I shouldn't remove that input line